How can I intercept redirects in Playwright tests?
In my Playwright test I'm using a route interceptor to add a header to every request:
return context.route('**/*', (route, request) => {
        return route.continue({
            headers: {
                ...request.headers(),
                'X-My-Header': myValue,
            }
        });
    });

This mostly works, EXCEPT when the application returns a redirect response in which case playwright follows the redirect without re-invoking my interceptor. The header is not sent with the redirected request.
Is there any way I can intercept the redirect?
